# ArangoError 2001: not able to connect and work with arangodb using docker?

Tags: docker, arangodb, arangojs

I am new to Arangodb, and docker realm as well, and I am trying to play with some data in the database using arangosh. But whenever I try to create and issue a command on the DB I get this error:

[image]

I would really appreciate it if you can explain why this is happening and how to solve it.

Thank you

Comment: It seems that problem was sovled when I used `docker run -e ARANGO_NO_AUTH=1` instead of `docker run -e ARANGO_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=1`

Comment: Do you run arangosh as another container, from inside the arangod (server) container, or directly on your system (without Docker) to connect to ArangoDB? If you want to run the client tool in another container, then that probably requires some network setup of Docker, so that it is allowed to connect to the other container. It's easier if you run it inside the server container, or expose the server port locally and run arangosh directly (client tool-only packages are available).